# Flow of two way communication using pipes

Tags: linux, ipc

```
pipe(fd1);


pipe(fd2);


pid_t pId = fork();
if(pId < 0 )
{
    printf("fork() failed\n");
    exit(-1);
}
if(pId == 0)
{

    close(fd1[1]);
    read(fd1[0], &num, sizeof(var));
    printf("Value: %d\n", num);

    int i;
    for(i=num-1; i> 0; i--) {
        num = num*i;
    }

    close(fd2[0]);
    write(fd2[1], &num, sizeof(num));
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
else 
{

    close(fd1[0]);
    write(fd1[1], &var, sizeof(var));



    close(fd2[1]);
    read(fd2[0], &f, sizeof(num));

    printf("Factorial: %d \n", f);
}
```

Above code is an example of two communication between two related process. Can anyone please help me to understand basic flow of the message passing between process.

Comment: Which part of it don’t you understand?

Comment: parent will write first then child will read and write then parent will read. I am unable to understand that in parent child relationship first parent will execute then child. Here why parent is executing again when it is reading ?